# how to insert html code in mysql table using query

Tags: php, mysql

```
    INSERT INTO Products  (Backorderable , CategoryID , Cost , CostExTax , DetPage , Enabled , FreightMode , ImageFile , Inventory , LongDescription , LongDescriptionMode , PerUnitShippingCharge1 , PerUnitShippingCharge2 , PerUnitShippingCharge3 , PerUnitWeight , ProductCode , ProductColor , ProductName , ProductSize , QBModified , Service , ShortCode , ShortDescription , ShortDescriptionMode , UseColor , UseSize , PageTitle , MetaDescription , MetaKeywordList , UseDefaultPageTitle , UseGlobalMetaDesc , UseGlobalMetaKeywords , SortOrder , PlainTextDescription , IncludeInFeeds , Available , HidePrice , HideBuyButton , UnavailableMessage , dtModified , ProductID , RRP ) VALUES (0, NULL, 199, 0, -1, -1, NULL, N'images/stories/virtuemart/product/slice.jpg', 0, N'<P class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">The SLICE™ Fabrique is a revolutionary fabric-cutting tool that makes quilting easier. </SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Don't spend hours cutting intricate designs with scissors when you can save time by allowing the </SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">SLICE™</SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> Fabrique to do all the work for you. The </SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">SLICE™</SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> Fabrique works with design cards specifically customized for fabric so you can cut alphabets, numbers, flowers, icons, basic shapes, and more.</SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Apply a fusible web to your cotton fabric, felt or flannel and you are ready to start Slicing. If you can imagine it, you can </SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">SLICE™</SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> it.<SPAN>&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">The </SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">SLICE™</SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> Fabrique is unlike anything you have ever seen. It's a one-of-a-kind tool that fits within everybody's budget. Save time and money while creating projects that will last a lifetime. </SPAN></P><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial>The Machine comes with 3 replacement blades, blade adjustment wrench, 6x6" glass cutting mat, repostitionable adhesive, foam brush, 3- 6x6" fusable web sheets, quick start guide, apllique basics SD design card, design card book.</FONT></DIV></SPAN>
<P class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"></SPAN>&nbsp;</P>', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, N'37013', NULL, N'Slice Fabrique RRP $250.00', NULL, 0, 0, N'', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, N'', NULL, NULL, -1, -1, -1, NULL, NULL, -1, -1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 51, NULL);
```

i want to insert this record to the mysql table but due slahes problem it is not inserting the problem is that i can't use the mysql_real_escape_string i have to remove each quote manually **any function in mysql that can do that for me...i have thousands of record like that**

Answer (score 1):

Do not - and I repeat Do not put that stuff into the database. Just put the data into it. Then when extract it you can put the HTML/CSS bells and whistles around it.

Comment: it's dynamic layout that's why we are saving it into the data base

Comment: Just put into the database that it is layout 1, 2 ... Then when time come to refresh the web site just change the CSS. Besides injecting raw HTML into a page is a bad idea. It  may mess it up and make it look unprofessional. Also are those people putting raw HTML into your database? If so let me know as I could put you in touch with a multitude of advertisers that would ...